# I am having below error while running curl command using java in Mac where it gives IOException and says cannot run the program

Tags: java, json, rest, unix, curl

Below is my curl for a POST request in java:

```
String payload1 = "curl --location --request POST 'https://some_url/abc' \\\n" +
                    "--header 'Api-Key: RIQOWU-9asds943msd9d934nmwdw0d' \\\n" +
                    "--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \\\n" +
                    "--header 'BarId: di292sdk/dmasdaskdnasd934n3sda0334n5Yz1QlVnnTmJ39U4aJT8/9sdns/Xwpen/asdksaeibwae+292nsadsaweg3ARyWwAA0LuSDIL3s+A/EVkLoVhc=' \\\n" +
                    "--header 'Accept: application/json;v=2' \\\n" +
                    "--header 'Cookie: JSESSIONID=9SDKSDSD9M23B4D46BF663F2B51E75137' \\\n" +
                    "--data-raw '{\n" +
                    "\"AU\": \"EC\",\n" +
                    "    \"is\": \"is\",\n" +
                    "    \"ls\": \"js\",\n" +
                    "    \"Timestamp\": \"2021-06-26T18:43:00Z\"\n" +
                    "}'";
            ProcessBuilder process = new ProcessBuilder(payload1);
            Process p;
            p = process.start();
```

Below is the relevant data from response

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/local/Cellar/curl/7.71.1/bin/curl.exe --location --request POST '..........
: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at com.aws.s3.service.EntryPoint.POSTAPI(EntryPoint.java:343)
    at com.aws.s3.service.EntryPoint.main(EntryPoint.java:72)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:247)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    ... 2 more

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I've tried mentioning the path of curl too in the String like below but still getting the same error.

```
String payload1 = "/usr/local/Cellar/curl/7.71.1/bin/curl.exe "+"--location --request POST......above payload......"
```

Please let me know if what could be the cause of it not able to interpret curl command in java. Greatly appreciated!!

Comment: PC or Mac?  Where is the `curl` program located? Is it in the path when you attempt to invoke it from Java?

Comment: MAC. CURL is located in the second location I mentioned which is /usr/local/Cellar/curl/7.71.1/bin/curl I didn't really understand what you meant by third question. I've explicitly mentioned the path of curl like in the post and appended the command to it.

Comment: The command you pass to `ProcessBuilder` expects that the directory containing the `curl` executable is included in the current `PATH` environment variable.  Try changing the command to contain the absolute path to `curl`, as in `/usr/local/Cellar/curl/7.71.1/bin/curl.exe --location --request POST ...`

Comment: Yes thats what I tried exactly but still getting the same error.

Comment: When posting a stack trace, please post the entire, complete dump, do not edit or modify it or remove anything.

Comment: It's the whole curl command followed by below error:
: error=2, No such file or directory
 at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
 at com.aws.s3.service.EntryPoint.POSTAPI(EntryPoint.java:343)
 at com.aws.s3.service.EntryPoint.main(EntryPoint.java:72)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
 at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
 at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:247)
 at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
 at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
 ... 2 more

Comment: No, please [edit] your post and copy/paste the complete stack trace and error message. When posting debugging information it is critical that you copy/paste ALL of EXACTLY what you see on your terminal, including all "caused by" sections.  I.e. the WHOLE stack trace.

Comment: Also update the question to show the actual string submitted to `ProcessBuilder`.  Print out the value of `payload1` and copy/paste it into the question.

Comment: Sorry, the data in curl command is confidential and so I cant post it. I've tried my best to simulate the actual curl by randomly just changing the characters in values and I can safely say it isn't working because of the meat of the curl command maybe incorrect. I've tried with curl of a simple POST request too without any multipart data which is throwing the same error too.

Comment: Could you show the latest version and calls you make on process or p after start?

Comment: Code:
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(payload1);
System.out.println(process.getInputStream().toString());
System.out.println(process.getOutputStream().toString());
System.out.println(process.getErrorStream().toString());
process.destroy();

Output:
curl.exists()=true
Files.isExecutable()=true
java.lang.UNIXProcess$ProcessPipeInputStream@332a7fce
java.lang.UNIXProcess$ProcessPipeOutputStream@549621f3
java.lang.UNIXProcess$ProcessPipeInputStream@54361a9
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:54990', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 0

Answer (score 2):

Are you certain the path to curl is correct - does it end ".exe"? I would have thought Mac version had no ".exe".  Validate the executable path used in the call with:

```
 File curl = new File("/usr/local/Cellar/curl/7.71.1/bin/curl"); 
 System.out.println("curl.exists()="+curl.exists());
 System.out.println("Files.isExecutable()="+Files.isExecutable(curl.toPath()));
```

Runtime.exec has `Runtime.exec(String)` but there is no  `ProcessBuilder(String)` - that has `ProcessBuilder(String ...)`. As your parameter is complex switch to String[], and this rules out issue with punctuation inside your command which will not require the line continuation values `\\\n` :

```
 String [] payload1 = new String[] { curl.getAbsolutePath(), 
       "--location", "--request", "POST"
     , "https://some_url/abc"
     , "--header", "Api-Key: RIQOWU-9asds943msd9d934nmwdw0d"
     
 ... etc

     , "--data-raw", "{\n" +
                "\"AU\": \"EC\",\n" +
                "    \"is\": \"is\",\n" +
                "    \"ls\": \"js\",\n" +
                "    \"Timestamp\": \"2021-06-26T18:43:00Z\"\n" +
                "}"
 };
```

Now you have Pipe errors, so if you send data to the process getOutputstream you should close() it, and ideally redirect the process output and error streams to file with:

process.redirectOutput(file);
process.redirectError(file):

Comment: So it returned true by removing .exe after curl but am still getting the same error after implementing AbsolutePath. I wonder why it's not able to digest curl command even though now able to find the curl file :(
curl.exists()=true
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/local/Cellar/curl/7.71.1/bin/curl --location --request POST

Comment: Are you definitely using ProcessBuilder, or Runtime.exec? If ProcessBuilder try launch with String[] - have amended my answer.

Comment: Yes I am using ProcessBuilder. I did try using Runtime.exec() and below was my code and response using Runtime.exec() command:
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(payload1);
System.out.println(process.getInputStream());
System.out.println(process.getOutputStream());
System.out.println(process.getErrorStream());

O/P:
curl.exists()=true
java.lang.UNIXProcess$ProcessPipeInputStream@72f46e16
java.lang.UNIXProcess$ProcessPipeOutputStream@3c9168dc
java.lang.UNIXProcess$ProcessPipeInputStream@332a7fce
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:58596', transport: 'socket'

Comment: On your previous comment, apart from using String [] do you also mean I should remove all \\n and plus (+) and use a comma (,) instead  ?

Comment: Yes all command line argument items should be separate entries in String[]. Those that are quoted `'` are one value not two. It maybe OK with the final raw data with \n but remove those if it does not work. If you need data back you would need to set `process.redirectOutput(file)` and `process.redirectError(file)`.

Comment: Upon using Runtime.exec() and the String[] I am still getting the same output as below:
curl.exists()=true
Files.isExecutable()=true
java.lang.UNIXProcess$ProcessPipeInputStream@3932c79a
java.lang.UNIXProcess$ProcessPipeOutputStream@782859e
java.lang.UNIXProcess$ProcessPipeInputStream@23f5b5dc

Is it able to execute curl at this point and get past filenotfound exception initially?